# How do I change Chrome's new tab page in incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome

I installed Earth View from Google Earth extension, but it won't show up in the  new tab page in incognito mode. How can I configure that page?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go in `chrome://extensions` 
Find your extension, and tick "Allow in incognito" box. Maybe this will help

Comment: I ticked that already, but it still shows `You’ve gone incognito` in the new tab page.

Comment: I think you need reset your chrome to fix that problem.

Comment: I did a fresh install in a virtual machine but the problem still exists, so I don't think that's necessarily related. The new tab page in incognito mode might have been strictly overridden by the incognito detail page. We need to find the corresponding configuration for that.